# oozie Pig action lauching Error

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am trying to do very basic oozie workflow

I am getting the below error wheni give the command..

```
user@ubuntu:~/surender$ oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie /home/user/surender/oozie_demo/job.properties -run
```

Error:

```
 Error: E0501 : E0501: Could not perform authorization operation, Failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException; Host Details : local host is: "ubuntu/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "localhost":8020;
```

My oozie version is 4.0.0 , I checked that oozie web console is enabled..

This is how created a oozie workflow

I created a directory called oozie_demo and inside that i created two files

```
    1.workflow.xml
    2.job.properties
```

I also created a lib directory and placed the pig script inside that lib directory

**workflow.xml**

```
 <workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.2" name="pig-wf"> 
<start to="pig-node"/> 
 <action name="pig-node"> 
     <pig> 
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker> 
         <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node> 
        <prepare> 
            <delete path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/output/pig/simple_load"/> 
        </prepare> 
        <configuration> 
            <property> 
               <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name> 
              <value>${queueName}</value> 
           </property> 
            <property> 
                 <name>mapred.compress.map.output</name> 
                <value>true</value> 
            </property> 
         </configuration> 
        <script>simple_load.pig</script> 
        <param>INPUT=/user/${wf:user()}/inputfiles/records.txt</param> 
       <param>OUTPUT=/user/${wf:user()}//output/pig/simple_load</param> 
     </pig> 
    <ok to="end"/> 
   <error to="fail"/> 
 </action> 
<kill name="fail"> 
    <message>Pig failed,     error                                                                                    message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message> 
    </kill> 
     <end name="end"/> 
    </workflow-app>
```

**job.properties**

```
    nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
    jobTracker=localhost:8021
    queueName=default  
    oozie_demo=oozie_demo 
    oozie.use.system.libpath=true
    ozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/user/oozie_demo
```

**my pig script :**

```
  records = load '/user/user/inputfiles/records.txt' USING PigStorage(',');

  store records into '/user/user/output/pig/simple_load' using PigStorage(',');
```

Could somebody help me on this? I would like to know what went wrong? and how do i resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if the Namenode is up and running at port 8020.